# Why does jacoco:check give an error when I create a test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jacoco

I am using IntelliJ and when I run my project it works fine with jacoco and all dependencies.

When I create a test class I suddenly get an error and I don't understand why.

The error I get is this one.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:check (jacoco-check) on project 
statistik-jar: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following 
articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :statistik-jar
```

When I have one test class, it works fine, but it gives this error when I add one more. The folder looks like this when I get the error:

```
/Test
   /test.class  <-- working
   /folder
      /test2.class <-- gives a error
```

This error occurs when creating a second class

Comment: @HoRn The intellij-idea tag seem irrelevant to this Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Jacoco works with percentile if you create more classes and do not have relative tests it will give the error.

```
                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                        <minimum>0.xx</minimum>
```

Check these data. I will give you some insight.

Comment: i have a minimum of 0.4. How can i make a relative test?

Comment: Dude, change this 0.1 or somthing and run the converage check whether it works then use the below thing to find the coverage missed lines.
 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-coverage-measurement.html

Comment: I found out about the problem, and also understand much more now. My question is does jacoco focuses on test if the phase being checked is test?